# What is the difference between calibration and training?

Tags: statistics

what is the difference between calibration and training process in theory?

For calibration we should define a range for each calibrated parameters, but in training there is no need to do this. However, I'm not sure how to describe their differences mathematically.

Comment: This is quite vague, but generally speaking "calibration" is used when the model is set in advance, in particular the error function is set in advance and the issue is "simply" to set open parameters in such a way that the error function is minimized. In "training" we typically don't have such  precise, pre-set notions.  Maybe the goal is "win chess games" or something like that.  Provisional metrics must be tried and then set aside or strengthened.

Comment: Thanks @lulu for the clear and simple explanation. So if I have a fixed model (e.g. physical based models) contains some calibrated parameters, the only calibration method is enough and there is no need to do training?

Comment: Again, this is all quite vague.  And it can be extremely difficult to find the parameters the minimize some general error function (if there even is a unique minimum).  But based on that general description, with no further context, I'd tend to agree with that.

Comment: to stress:  one could make the case that this is just semantics.  If you are dealing with a family of models (indexed by some parameter set, say), then you are just looking for the "best" parameters given the available data.   Exactly what "best" means depends on the context and might not be absolutely clear.  Sometimes "best" is unambiguously defined and sometimes it isn't.  Clarifying that is the important issue, not what you call the process.

Comment: Thanks@lulu! So I think fit any model (beyond having fix structure or not) needs training. Because to find a best solution (minimizing or maximizing the objective function) there should be the trade-off between bias and variance, and it is not absolutely clear. I am not sure if I am right or wrong :)

Comment: Again, this is all so vague that it feels like a semantics issue.  In any real world model there are tradeoffs.  Error functions are seldom obvious and two reasonable people might disagree over what constitutes the best fit.  That's the issue one should focus on, not the name you give the process.